# How to add a shortcode which runs a .php file for the current post

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode

RESOLVED: In the end, I found a non-php coding solution, but thank you to those who replied!

My client is using Woocommerce Bookings for tours which are saved as Woocommerce Products. I have just redesigned their site using a page builder for ease of future updates, etc for them. However, I cannot for the life of me work out how to get the Woocommerce Booking form onto the newly designed Single Product Template page! There appears to be no shortcodes included natively...

I have the .php file which runs to pull the form in, and I have found instructions on how to add a new shortcode using the page builder. However, I have no idea what to put inside the shortcode creation to get it to run the form .php code - further complicated by my needing it to run for the current product at the time....

Here is the code to create the shortcode

```
function wpc_elementor_shortcode( $atts ) {
    echo "This is my custom PHP output in Elementor!";
}
add_shortcode( 'my_elementor_php_output', 'wpc_elementor_shortcode');
```

Happy to provide further information if needed!

Comment: Does `get_template_part()` is useful for this purpose? it loads a template part into a template, but shortcode should return a value (not "echo"), maybe with output buffering it will be useful)

Comment: Shortcodes can't `echo` their content, they _must_ return it. It should be `return "This is my custom PHP output..";`. The same is true of any custom PHP code you run, it must be returned. If you do not do this, then the shortcode will break lots of things, e.g. it won't work nested inside other shortcodes, it can appear in the wrong order at the start of content, break RSS/REST/XMLRPC responses, etc

Comment: That's weird - the above code is exactly what it says to use to create a shortcode for the page builder I am using.

Regardless, any ideas on what code to use for the case above? I need it to run php code that is saved as a seperate .php file for the current post...

Comment: Have you tried to include the php file within the shortcode..? Would be helpful to know what you've tried. Also, what do you mean by "run php code"? Is there a function in the file? Will the code you need run with an include? Does the code output something or store a variable. more info needed.

Comment: Paul - I haven't tried adding anything yet. I don't know coding really, have just been learning along the way so far...! Essentially, I have a .php file that creates the booking form and I need to make that code run within the above to create a shortcode. Does that make sense??